# Properly using tf.GradientTape().gradient

Tags: tensorflow

This is not a code question, but a "how it works" morelike one. I have a model which has as inputs 4 `tf.Tensor()` of same shapes `(60, 200, 15000)`. And my output is a `tf.Tensor` with shape `(60, 200)`. My custom loss changes the shape of all 4 tensors to output's shape so here there is no problem. Then, inside my custom loss, I measure the loss and compute it. My question comes after, by doing `loss = tf.GradientTape().gradient(loss_fn, model.trainable_variables)` and `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(loss, model.trainable_variables)`.

How does the gradient "know" which variables to apply itself? How can I know if the gradient is properly made?

Comment: What do you mean by: "How can I know if the gradient is properly made?"?

Comment: @AloneTogether i mean, how can I know that the loss I've created does affect positively my model gradient applied?

Comment: Can you show an example in your question?

Comment: @AloneTogether thx for answering, but I don't have any example. I want to know how the gradient function works and how a custom loss can affect it, sorry if I'm explaining it with poor words